# How to send data to a particular Client from server?

Tags: vb.net, sockets

I have programmed a chat application in VB but as soon as I send any data from a client the server will send it to all.  It should send a reply only to a particular client.
This is the function I have used.

```
Dim objClient As Client
Dim d As DictionaryEntry
For Each d In mcolClients
    objClient = d.Value
    objClient.Send(Data & vbLf)
Next
```

Where `mcolClients` is a hash table.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at your code:

```
' Declare your variables
Dim objClient As Client
Dim d As DictionaryEntry

' For every client in the hash table
For Each d In mcolClients
    objClient = d.Value
    ' Send the data to the client.
    objClient.Send(Data & vbLf)
Next
```

This does exactly what you'd expect it to, i.e. send `Data` to every connected client that's in the `HashTable`.

Your question was, how do you send the data to one particular client, rather than all of them.  To give a specific answer, more details would be required about what is trying to be achieved / how your current code is structured.  But here are some general options...

- If the goal is to send to everybody but the client that the data was received from, then you could modify your current code so that in addition to `Data` it also supplied `receivedFromClient`, then do not send the data where `d.Value` was `receivedFromClient`.
- If the goal is to send a response back to the client that sent the message (like an 'ack'), simply do it at the point of receipt, you don't need to refer to your `HashTable` at all (at the point you're reading data, you should know who you're reading it from).
- If the goal is to send to a specific client then you need two things:

  1. A way to identify the client connection (so possibly store a `UserName` in the `Client` object that is inserted into the `HashTable` for example.  This `UserName` might be supplied by the client when it first connections for example as part of your 'chat' protocol.
  2. A way to specify the target client, such as target `UserName`, which could be looked up in the hash table.  So, the a client could send `@somebody here's a secret message` to send the text `here's a secret message` to the `Client` in the `HashTable` with a `UserName` attribute of `somebody`.  This received string would need to be processed to extract the relevant username token.  It would also seem to make sense to consider using `UserName` as the key for the `HashTable`, if that is going to be the primary reason for performing lookups.